# How to disable long touch = click on MacBook Air touchpad?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

If I leave my mouse in one spot for several seconds with my finger on the touch pad, it interprets it as a downclick.  So if I hover over a file while thinking about something and then move my cursor, it will try to drag the file, if I hover over text and then move the cursor it will select text, and so on.

I have gone into the System Settings and unchecked "Tap to Click" already, but that doesn't seem to do it. Is there another way to disable this feature?

Comment: Have you got any Application which either modifies or enhances the behaviour and possibilities of the trackpad or the magic mouse?

Comment: No not that I know of.  I do have a magic mouse that I use sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was being caused by a faulty touch pad.  Not an entirely uncommon problem apparently.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put more than one finger on your pad ? Precisely, did you put exactly three fingers ? That may be your problem, and therefore your solution. In the preference menu, you can disable the "Three finger drag".

Comment: No, I've tested it a number of times.  One finger on the pad for about three seconds,  then touch and move the cursor with another finger.